# Adding fields in in c# to crystal report

Tags: c#

i want to display a set of report on my crystal report form in a app i develop using win form, c# and crystal report. i have 2 tables and wants to display a report from the two tables in one crystal report. here is the code

string sql = "select * from ISSUED, RECEIVED WHERE ISSUED.ITEMCODE=RECEIVED.ITEMCODE AND ISSUED.TRANSDATE,RECEIVED.TRANSDATE between'" + Convert.ToDateTime(date1) + "' and '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date2) + "' and ISSUED.ITEMCODE = '" + itemcode + "' and RECEIVED.ITEMCODE between '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date1) + "' and '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date2) + "'";

And this is the error i get 
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is exprected, near '.'.

Comment: "select * from ISSUED, RECEIVED " bad idea.  Use real JOINs.

Comment: I don't know why you are converting the date to a string using single quotes.  Try following : string sql = string.Format("select * from ISSUED, RECEIVED SUM (ISSUED.QTY_ISSUED) AS QTY_ISSUED, SUM (RECEIVED.QTY_RECEIVED) AS QTY_RECEIVED where ((Date between {0} and {1}) and (ITEMCODE = '{2}')) GROUP BY ITEMCODE ORDER BY DATE", date1, date2, itemcode);